# Setting up OAuth in existing portal or as separate service?

Tags: php, oauth

I'm before task of setting oAuth server to be used for authorization mainly across few portals with one login.
How should I approach this? Should I create special server only for this purpose or integrate it into main portal?

Most preferably I would want to everyone be able to register account on any portal and login with same credetentials on other portals.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what philosophy you subscribe to.  Generally in this day and age of microservices, virtualization and autoscaling garbage code across 40 servers because it costs to much to do it correctly, the separate server is generally the way to go; but you should think about scaling and maintenance requirements for your project before arriving at decision.